# HTTPS and Volley Calls being blocked by BT wifi modem

Tags: android, http, android-volley, wifi

I have an Android app that uses Volley to retrieve JSON from a simple web service (uses a PHP script)

One user reported issues and no matter what I did, the app wouldn't work on his Wifi. It worked on mobile data, but not wifi.

I sent him the URL that my app calls to try in his phone's browser. Once he did this the expected JSON showed in his browser. Then, all of a sudden, my app then started working for him. It had never worked on his home wifi before.

Withing a minute or two, he got an email from BT saying that a new website had been added to the allowed list of websites.

So, it seems that the BT wifi modem was blocking all calls from my app.

How can I work around this, I can't be sending URLs to users to get their BT settings to whitelist my website.I could load my website in a webview in the background as the app loads for the very first time, but I don't like this solution very much.

Could it be something in the way I am calling the URL using Volley? Are there other headers I needs to supply?

All ideas welcome.

Comment: that is not your problem, that is his modem settings problem. It trusts only URLs he already opened from his web browser. This is not you who has to do something about it.

Comment: I have a large number of users, so many users may be affected. I was hoping there is some way to get my app to work without having to get each user to make manual modem settings changes. Other apps are working fine for these users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vladyslav

Comment: nobody knows why the modem is blocking it. You have to understand why it is happening first before trying to fix it. But we can't help with that, as nobody here knows how those modems work. Nobody even knows which exactly modem is there.

Comment: No problem, thanks.

Comment: All other ideas welcome please!